# python "string" module?

Tags: python, string, module, deprecated

So I'm reading this old module from I think around 2002 and it has this line "import string". Did Python require you to import a string module explicitly before to be able to use string type variables or something? I don't see it used like this in the code:

```
string.something
```

Comment: It is still around: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Answer (score 7):

The `string` module contains [a set of useful constants](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html?highlight=string%20module#string-constants), such as `ascii_letters` and `digits`, and the module is often still imported for that reason.

Answer (score 6):

If you see a `import string` but never see `string.something`, someone just forgot to remove an unused import.

While there *did* use to be some things in `string` that are now standard methods of `str` objects, you still had to either

1. prefix them with `string.` after importing the library, or
2. use `from string import <whatever>` syntax.

Typically, the only times you'll see something properly imported but never "explicitly used" are `from __future__ import with_statement` or the like - the forwards/backwards compatability triggers used by Python for new language features.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ambar said, it seems to be a redundant import, and RoeeeK is also right in saying that most of the `string` module's functions are meanwhile string methods, i.e. you can do `"foobar".method()` instead of `string.function("foobar")`. However, sometimes it is still useful to explicitely import the module; for instance, in the case of callbacks:

`map(string.strip, [' foo ', ' bar '])`.

Note that the above can also be achieved by `[chunk.strip() for chunk in [' foo ', ' bar ']]`, so importing `string` is actually not required in this case.

Comment: `map(str.strip, [' foo ', ' bar '])`

Comment: Ah, nice. I feel like I should have known this, but somehow, I didn't. Thanks for pointing that out, even though it makes my answer pointless. :)

Answer (score 0):

well, in older versions the string module was indeed much more useful, but in the recent versions most of the string module functions are available also as string methods..

this page will give you a better look:
http://effbot.org/librarybook/string.htm