# Is there a reason to import the string module in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am a beginner in programming and Python is my first language. I am using a Python shell right now, but don't understand why we need to import the `string` module.

I know that importing `string` imports some functions, but when I tried using functions like `string.split` and `string.join`, they all work without the import, so I assume that means that they are just Python builtins.

Is there anything that works once you import the `string` module that wouldn't work otherwise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python "string" module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370266/python-string-module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you don't need to import `string` module as the class is already in builtins.  However, there are several [constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) that are in the string module that are not built in, that can be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a need these days. You most likely shouldn't need to ever use `import string`.

You can find a list [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#) of the components inside of the `string` library, but as it says most have been added into the rest of the standard library now. It's just the way that it used to be set up in Python many years ago. `string` mostly has a bunch of constants now.

From the comments in the [source file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/string.py)

> A collection of string operations (most are no longer used).
>
> Warning: most of the code you see here isn't normally used nowadays.
> Beginning with Python 1.6, many of these functions are implemented as
> methods on the standard string object. They used to be implemented by
> a built-in module called strop, but strop is now obsolete itself.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is `cmd`'s answer below. `strop` is obsolete, but the `string` module provides constants that are still useful.

Answer (score 0):

That only works with `import string`.:

```
import string \n
text = open(input('Enter file (.txt):')) \n
for line in text: 
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('', '',string.punctuation))
```

I tried it without and it didn't work. This function (line 3) is for replacing and deleting things in a string.
So I guess that `import string` still has functions that wouldn't work without it.